# Is it possible to populate two columns simultaneously?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

I have a lookup table with three columns:

```
ID Brand Product
1  Dell   Computer
4  HP     Printer
```

I have to fill one more table as follows :

```
ID  Product Brand
1
```

On click of Product the following formula: `=VLOOKUP(A2,$E$4:$G$7,3,FALSE)` will populate the `Product` as `Printer`. I want the corresponding `Brand` also to be populated on click of `Product`. The value to be populated should be `HP`.

I tried using the formula `=VLOOKUP(A2,A3,$E$4:$G$7,3,2,FALSE)` but it says *Too many arguments*.

Is it possible to populate two columns simultaneously?

If not possible using VLOOKUP, is there any other way of populating multiple cells by clicking on some other cell?

Comment: Just use two formulas - what would be the advantage of using one?

Comment: 'Is it possible to have one cell affect 2 others?' Yes, by having each of _those_ cells refer back to it, of course. 'Is there any other way?' A macro, but please avoid those wherever possible...

Answer (score 3):

One way to populate multiple cells by a single click is to use a Form Control. In the example, G2 is populated with:

```
=IF($A3,VLOOKUP($A3,$A:$C,COLUMN()-5,0),"")
```

with this copied across to H2.

In 'A3' is a Check Box linked to A3:

[image: SO33035239 first example]

A single click on the Check Box should then display:

[image: SO33035239 second example]

Comment: This use of `column` to do relative `lookup`s can be applied to other situations, of course. I've even come up with some nifty tricks combining this with named ranges, in a past life.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot populate a cell with a formula in another cell. You need one formula for Product and another formula for Brand.

For Product you have `=VLOOKUP(A2,$E$4:$G$7,3,FALSE)`, which returns the value in the **third** column of the lookup table.

For Brand you want to return the **second** column of the lookup table. Therefore, you need this formula in the Brand column:

```
                          v-- This is the column you want to return
    =VLOOKUP(A2,$E$4:$G$7,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Yes absolutely correct, but I want to populate Both Brand and Product probably clicking on ID

Comment: Then put respective formulae in all cells that you want `lookup`ed. This is not difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate two VLOOKUPs and have both values in on cell like so:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$E$4:$G$7,2,FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP(A2,$E$4:$G$7,3,FALSE)
```